Why my control-plane node unexpected went to "Not Ready"?
Server running fine and seems unexpected lost of connection, I have attached the main logs of messages, and I will explain my analysis:
Sep 26 07:11:39 kubelet started to show "Error updating node status"
At 07:12:00 Lost connection with the pods running in qos1
Sep 26 07:12:03 kubelet shows that update node exceeds retry count.
The logs repeat again and again.
Sep 26 07:16:25 qos1 sssd_be[1077]: Backend is offline
And almost 6 hours later  qos server got reconnected and I can access the server.
One thing that catches my attention is  the following log:
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 Keepalived_vrrp[1512]: Interface cali9f8d8b57766 deleted
Nominally there is always a previous log indicating that the inteface cali****** has been added but for cali9f8d8b57766 interface it does not show.
Keepalived has been working perfectly and it does not show any restart or shutdown.
Logs
Sep 26 07:11:39 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:39.898515    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:447] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "qos1": Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1>
Sep 26 07:11:42 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 07:11:42.224462    1395 scope.go:95] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: 4419c100277e962e208697d965304fb277f0e9616bf8b9d1b27028ff73747494
Sep 26 07:11:42 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 07:11:42.232446    1395 scope.go:95] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: d291467393cf1e5e821ead0a0e8df2286456d728ae2a8653c4f3144056738746
Sep 26 07:11:44 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:44.921847    1395 controller.go:187] failed to update lease, error: Put "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/l>
Sep 26 07:11:49 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:49.899005    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:447] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "qos1": Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1>
Sep 26 07:11:49 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:49.899347    1395 event.go:273] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"kube-apiserver>
Sep 26 07:11:49 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:49.899541    1395 controller.go:187] failed to update lease, error: Put "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/l>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: W0926 07:11:57.071447    1395 status_manager.go:550] Failed to get status for pod "kube-apiserver-qos1_kube-system(bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c512d)": Get "://>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071492    1395 event.go:273] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"kube-apiserver>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071576    1395 controller.go:187] failed to update lease, error: Put "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/l>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071607    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy-token-sgfj8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namesp>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071628    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"calico-node-token-g2jkf": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/names>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071648    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kubernetes-services-endpoint": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071670    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071675    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/services?>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071692    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"qos-configmap": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/defau>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071588    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"default-token-vjg8j": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/de>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071677    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-token-rmsn8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-mast>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071588    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"promtail-token-8jxf2": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/d>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071686    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:447] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "qos1": Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071510    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/po>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071688    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/storage.k>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071699    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"promtail": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/co>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071699    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:438: Failed to watch *v1.Node: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/nodes?all>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071705    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/node.k>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071688    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"repo-secret": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/defau>
Sep 26 07:11:57 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:11:57.071914    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"calico-config": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1/namespaces/k>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143692    1395 controller.go:187] failed to update lease, error: Put "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/l>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143749    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"qos-configmap": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-maste>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143785    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"calico-config": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-m>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143785    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-token-rmsn8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: W0926 07:12:00.143777    1395 status_manager.go:550] Failed to get status for pod "kube-apiserver-qos1_kube-system(bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c512d)": Get "://>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143814    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:447] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "qos1": Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143860    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "://vip-k>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143884    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "://vip-k8s->
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143887    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-mast>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143887    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"promtail": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:844>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143896    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "://vip->
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143900    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy-token-sgfj8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143896    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"calico-node-token-g2jkf": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143928    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kubernetes-services-endpoint": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "ht>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143930    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.RuntimeClass: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get ":>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143954    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"promtail-token-8jxf2": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-mast>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143903    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"default-token-vjg8j": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-maste>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143939    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:438: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "://vip-k8s-mas>
Sep 26 07:12:00 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:00.143996    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"repo-secret": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216013    1395 controller.go:187] failed to update lease, error: Put "://vip-k8s-master:8443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/l>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 07:12:03.216055    1395 controller.go:114] failed to update lease using latest lease, fallback to ensure lease, err: failed 5 attempts to update lease
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216153    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "://vip->
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216191    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"default-token-vjg8j": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-maste>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216196    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"calico-node-token-g2jkf": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216209    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-mast>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216197    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "://vip-k8s->
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216228    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:438: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "://vip-k8s-mas>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216207    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy-token-sgfj8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216196    1395 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "://vip-k>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216219    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"repo-secret": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: Get "://vip-k8s-master:8>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216247    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"promtail": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "://vip-k8s-master:844>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216259    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-token-rmsn8": Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216269    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:447] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "qos1": Get "://vip-k8s-master:8443/api/v1>
Sep 26 07:12:03 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 07:12:03.216289    1395 kubelet_node_status.go:434] Unable to update node status: update node status exceeds retry count

........
Sep 26 07:16:25 hadg-qos1 sssd_be[1077]: Backend is offline
........

Sep 26 13:10:44 qos1 sssd_be[1077]: Backend is online
Sep 26 13:10:45 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 13:10:45.978649    1395 reflector.go:138] object-"default"/"qos-configmap": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: configmaps "qos-configmap">
Sep 26 13:10:48 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:48 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ee ee ee ee ee ee c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:10:49 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:49 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ee ee ee ee ee ee c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:10:50 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:50 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ee ee ee ee ee ee c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:10:53 qos1 kubelet[1395]: W0926 13:10:53.437429    1395 status_manager.go:550] Failed to get status for pod "kube-apiserver-qos1_kube-system(bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c512d)": etcdserver: r>
Sep 26 13:10:54 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:10:54.745719    1395 scope.go:95] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bfd622da14c9198815ed7a7de6d0a801c5386b83e8d586ababf51bdbfcd5c20e
Sep 26 13:10:54 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 13:10:54.746207    1395 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c512d ("kube-apiserver-qos1_kube-system(bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c5>
Sep 26 13:10:57 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:57 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:10:58 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:58 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:10:59 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:10:59 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:01 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:01 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:02 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:02 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:03 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:03 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:05 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:05.747853    1395 scope.go:95] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bfd622da14c9198815ed7a7de6d0a801c5386b83e8d586ababf51bdbfcd5c20e
Sep 26 13:11:05 qos1 kubelet[1395]: E0926 13:11:05.748376    1395 pod_workers.go:191] Error syncing pod bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c512d ("kube-apiserver-qos1_kube-system(bd07a1d7d39af16cc73c0692e91c5>
Sep 26 13:11:06 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:06 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:07 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:07 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:08 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:08 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:09.850369    1395 topology_manager.go:187] [topologymanager] Topology Admit Handler
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer container kubepods-besteffort-podf435a11f_605c_4641_a1bf_b7be0e3bde13.slice.
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:09.965787    1395 reconciler.go:224] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kube-config" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/empty>
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:09.965869    1395 reconciler.go:224] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kubernetes-admin-config" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.i>
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:09.965924    1395 reconciler.go:224] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "default-token-vjg8j" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/se>
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 kubelet[1395]: I0926 13:11:09.966071    1395 reconciler.go:224] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "ha-job-script" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configma>
Sep 26 13:11:09 qos1 systemd[1]: docker-3a7450a83fbc2166609b2cfacec9cb70124a4240d2caafe79d6cdcc6dccf60c0.scope: Succeeded.
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 systemd[1]: docker-3a7450a83fbc2166609b2cfacec9cb70124a4240d2caafe79d6cdcc6dccf60c0.scope: Consumed 3d 18h 17min 36.853s CPU time
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 containerd[1118]: time="2024-09-26T13:11:10.010120865Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=3a7450a83fbc2166609b2cfacec9cb70124a4240d2caafe79d6cdcc6dccf60c0
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 containerd[1118]: time="2024-09-26T13:11:10.010233715Z" level=error msg="copy shim log" error="read /proc/self/fd/68: file already closed"
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 dockerd[1926482]: time="2024-09-26T13:11:10.010278638Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=3a7450a83fbc2166609b2cfacec9cb70124a4240d2caafe79d6cdcc6dccf60c0 module=libcontainerd >
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-f2e0d9992772c2bc46a4356d189cb63facac502e374ca32d327f37a591e1c564-merged.mount: Succeeded.
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 kernel: IPv4: martian source X.X.X.X from X.X.X.X, on dev cali9f8d8b57766
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff c6 4e 64 5a 15 9d 08 06
Sep 26 13:11:10 qos1 Keepalived_vrrp[1512]: Interface cali9f8d8b57766 deleted

What did you expect to happen?
It should not occur and or at least not lose connection with the server.  The node was not ready and recovered itself after almost 6 hours.
How can we reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)?
I have 9 nodes, 3 control-plane, master and 6 workers.
qos1 is one of the 3 control-plane, master
Anything else we need to know?
This is the second time this occurs, first time the node was ready instantly but this time the node was "Not Ready" for almost 6 hours.
The other 2 nodes [control-plane, master] have not shown this behavior.
Kubernetes version
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
(machine is running in 2020 so ignore date)

Cloud provider

Bare metal

OS version
# On Linux:
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.5"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.5"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.5"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:5:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.5
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.5
$ uname -a
Linux qos2 5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Oct 2 14:39:04 PDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(machine is running in 2020 so ignore date)


You may want to try this on a supported release of Oracle Linux 8. Oracle typically supports the latest point release of Oracle Linux (some Oracle database products may also have RTM support). This is due to the prevalence of customers running releases with critical vulnerabilities for years. 8.5 was released three years ago. Note this is different from other distribution vendors, RHEL may have updates that target a point release. https://endoflife.date/oracle-linux https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-oracle-linux-for-minor-releases-2173
